# ListView Changing Items During Scroll

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I am implementing a ListFragment using a custom ArrayAdapter to populate the list. Each row item has an ImageView and three TextViews. Data is being parsed via XML and the images are being async loaded.

The problem I am having is that the ListView populates and looks good, but there is a problem when scrolling. I can fit 7 items on the screen at once. When I scroll to the 8th, it changes suddenly so the next row that should be appearing. It only does it on rows divisible by 8 (ie. rows 8, 16, 24, etc).

I'm using the ViewHolder pattern to ensure good speed with this ListView. I figure the problem lies in there somewhere, but I have searched around and it appears I am doing this pattern correctly and I have run out of things to check in order to resolve this issue. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MyViewHolder holder;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.browse_result_list_item, null, false);
        holder = new MyViewHolder();
        holder.adTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.adTitle);
        holder.region = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.region);
        holder.time = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.time);
        holder.thumbnail = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.browseThumbnail);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    SearchResult result = mObjects.get(position);

    holder.adTitle.setText(result.getTitle().substring(0, result.getTitle().length()-3)); // three ... at the end, remove them
    holder.region.setText(result.getRegion());
    holder.time.setText(result.getPostingTime());

    // Download the image thumbnail
    ArrayList<String> urls = result.getImageUrls();
    if (urls.size() > 0)
        download(urls.get(0), holder.thumbnail);
    else // No image for this post, put a placeholder
        holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_picture);

    return row;
}

private static class MyViewHolder {
    public static TextView adTitle;
    public static TextView region;
    public static TextView time;
    public static ImageView thumbnail;
}
```

**Edit:** I found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540582/list-view-image-is-getting-changed-when-scrolling) thanks to @frozenkoi. Ended up being the static variables inside the ViewHolder causing problems. They are now simply public and the class is static and the issue has bee solved.

Comment: You don't show the code for the `download` function. Most likely when you're scrolling you have two async downloads update the same `ImageView`. You need to ensure that when the `ListView` recycles a row's view that it is only updated by the correct downloader and not for the downloader meant for the row the view was representing before.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540582/list-view-image-is-getting-changed-when-scrolling

Comment: Should that sentence read "it changes suddenly **to** the next row that should be appearing." instead?

Can you give a little example of the effect?


    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7

becomes what?

Comment: More info on lazy loading images in a list or grid view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Comment: check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789676/caching-images-and-displaying. Lazy Loading

Comment: I would try to get rid of the download code and try to use some resource or bitmap for all the images, if the problem disappears that the download code is to blame.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have solved the problem, thanks to @frozenkoi. Apparently in my ViewHolder class, having the variables static is what caused this problem! No more static, no more strange scroll issue in the list view. Also, I should note that during the debug, I disabled downloading images and just put a bitmap from resources in the row instead and there was no change. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to @frozenkoi. Ended up being the static variables inside the ViewHolder causing problems. They are now simply public and the class is static and the issue has been solved.

```
private static class MyViewHolder {
    public TextView adTitle;
    public TextView region;
    public TextView time;
    public ImageView thumbnail;
}
```

Comment: I am getting `The member type ViewHolder cannot be declared static; static types can only be declared in static or top level types`

Answer (score 3):

First of all define in `getView()` method into `convertView=null;`
and comment **else** condition in this method and add `int type = getItemViewType(position)`;.
Also remove static keyword from each View item like `Textview, ImageView` in ViewHolder class.

> NOTE: override getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType() in your
>   adapter.

```
if(convertView == null){
 switch (type) {
            case 0:
                  //First view[Row layout]
            break;
            case 1:
                 //Second view[Row layout]
            break;

            //another Case here....

   convertView.setTag(holder);

  //remove else part when used convertView =null;
        /*else {
        holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }*/

} 

@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        map = list.get(position); 
        message_type = map.get("message_type");
        if (message_type.equalsIgnoreCase("TEXT")) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (getCount() != 0)
            return getCount();
        return 2;
    }
```

**Do it now!
Done!**

Answer (score 1):

Just add these lines of code in your adapter class.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {

    if (getCount() != 0)
        return getCount();

    return 1;
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem comes only when viewholder variables are defined **static**.
Otherwise listview works good with or without viewholder in scroll.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!! Try to avoid comment in answer unless you have specific answer. Please use comment box below and Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case **revert back** was forgotten in `if else` condition:

```
/*public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public List<Contact> _data;
    private ArrayList<Contact> arraylist;
    Context _c;
    ViewHolder holder;

public ContactAdapter(List<Contact> contacts, Context context) {
    _data = contacts;
    _c = context;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(_data);
}*/
@Override
public View getView(final int i,  View convertView, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = convertView;
    final Contact data = (Contact) _data.get(i);
    ViewHolder holder ;

    if (view == null) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list, null,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pic);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.title.setText(data.getName());
    // Set image if is null string
    if(!data.getThumb().equals("null")){
        try {
             Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImageStorage.getImage(data.getThumb()).getAbsolutePath());
             holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
             holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.contactimage);
          }

    }else // I had forgotten this else 
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.contactimage); 


    // same action with background color
    if(data.getId()==data.getFromContact() ){
         view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
     } else{
         view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); //**revert back it**
     }
        return view;
}
```

ViewHolder

```
  private  static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView title;

}
```