# List Item child not refreshing

Tags: android, user-interface, listitem

I am writing an custom list, in which displayed 3rd list item has toggle button as an child. On toggle button click it launch an confirmation dialog,  if wants toggle button or not.

Now if list not scrolled then it work perfect. But if scroll list(so 3rd displayed as 1st item) then button toggle state(for `toggleButton.setChecked(false)`) not working after `Dialog-Cancel` action.

Any suggestion if I am missing anything.

**EDIT**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;

            if(convertView == null) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_prefernce_row, parent, false);
                final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtPreferenceName); // Preference Name
                viewHolder.txtPreferenceSub = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtPreferenceSub); // Sub-Preference Name

                viewHolder.txtArrow = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtArrow); // text before arrow
                viewHolder.imgArrow = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imgArrow); // right_arrow

                viewHolder.btnToggleState = (ToggleButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.tglToggleState); // toggle button
                viewHolder.switchTemperatureUnit = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.switchTemperatureUnit); // switch button for temperature

                //viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
                //viewHolder.scores.setTag(list.get(position));
                vi.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                vi = convertView;
            }

....

}
```

Comment: can you post some code also ?

Comment: Similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752239/listview-changing-items-during-scroll) issue .. And see [this](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Keeping-the-data-in-ListView-with-interactive-items-while-scrolling-in-Android-1621.php) also..

Comment: @NewDeveloper I don't think this is the same issue. What I am facing it, I need same view from original list index, not from updated one after scrolling.

Comment: Can you please getView code block alone?

Comment: @GKTHEBOSS there is lot in getView..I have initial of it.

Comment: Change `vi = convertView;` to `viewHolder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();`

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes that is there...it just I did not mentioned in code above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. After vi retrive via covertviiew .gettag and 
   retrieve checkbox object
2. Set the check box visibility to Gone (This code should run always)
3. Check if row is 3 (as you want) and make the visibility change
4. if toggle is visible the update the state based on model data
5. When ever toggle is changed update the model

These are the usual things that we need to do for this type specific requirement. If you didn't get the issue resolved let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize ViewHolder implementation damm required. And to get target item view following worked great.

```
for(int i = start, j = lstSettingPreference.getLastVisiblePosition(); i <= j; i++) {
                if (ordinal == (int) lstSettingPreference.getItemAtPosition(i)) {
                    view = lstSettingPreference.getChildAt(i - start);
                    lstSettingPreference.getAdapter().getView(i, view, lstSettingPreference);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Reference link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987616/2624806.